# Can't process the fetched data from server

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to fetch data with this code :

```
export const genres =()=>{
const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api";
fetch(apiUrl + "/genres")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const res = data.results
    return res
  }) 
}
```

then I want to use the outcome with this code

```
export function getGenres() {
  return genres.filter(g => g);
}
```

but I get this :TypeError: **genres.filter is not a function**.

what is my mistake and how to fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly** genres is not an array, but a function so filter won't be defined on it

**Secondly**, genres is not returning anything currently

**Thirdly**, genres is an async method so you need to handle promises.You can make use of async await for it

```
export const genres =()=>{
    const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api";

    return fetch(apiUrl + "/genres")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const res = data.results
        return res
      }) 

}

export async function getGenres() {
  try {
     const res = await genres();
     return res.filter(g => g);
  } catch(e) {
     console.log('err', e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`genres` is a function, so you can't use `filter` directly on that.

You could instead call the `genres` function and return the `fetch` promise and wait for it to resolve before you can do anything with `res`.

```
export const genres = () => {
  const apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api";

  return fetch(apiUrl + "/genres")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const res = data.results;
      return res;
    });
};

export function getGenres() {
  return genres().then(res => res.filter(g => g));
}
```